# Pyinstaller, python. pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm hoping that someone has encountered this error:

> pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing

```
pip install --force-reinstall --no-binary :all: pyinstaller didn't help

pip install --upgrade setuptools  didn't help either
```

Logs added below

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.9.0
Building directory: C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed  "C:/Users/E/Documents/GitHub/prog/prog_1_1.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed C:/Users/E/Documents/GitHub/prog/prog_1_1.py --distpath C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6\application --workpath C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6\build --specpath C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6

8122 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
8124 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
8131 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
8133 INFO: wrote C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6\prog_1_1.spec
8138 INFO: UPX is not available.
8158 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\E\\Documents\\GitHub\\prog',
 'C:\\Users\\E\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmph1ngej_6']
8397 INFO: checking Analysis
8415 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
8415 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
8425 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
8440 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
10220 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\E\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
10230 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\E\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib'
12174 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
12323 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
12351 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
12393 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\E\Documents\GitHub\prog\prog_1_1.py
12726 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\E\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\E\Desktop\auto-py-to-exe-master\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 126, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 815, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 762, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Temp\tmph1ngej_6\prog_1_1.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['C:/Users/E/Documents/GitHub/prog/prog_1_1.py'],
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 467, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 304, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).add_script(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2510, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1544, in import_hook
    for target_submodule in self._import_importable_package_submodules(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1794, in _import_importable_package_submodules
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 447, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 437, in _safe_import_module
    hook_module.pre_safe_import_module(hook_api)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py", line 33, in pre_safe_import_module
    raise SystemExit("pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.")
SystemExit: pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open cmd and just type `pip3 uninstall enum34`, then try again to convert.

Comment: It helps, thank you